# Python and bottle - how to get post data of a protocol bufer

Tags: python, bottle

I need to parse a protocol buffer send via a post using bottle.

How do I get PB to parse?

I tried the following but did nt work:

```
@post('/test')
def test():
    br = test_pb2.MyRequest()
    br.ParseFromString(request.files.data)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The raw body data is available through `request.body`, a file-like object (either a real file or a BytesIO depending on its size). `request.body.read()` should do the job for you.